# Python encodes (Korean) characters in an unexpected way with euc-kr encoding (codecs, encodings module)

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I tried to read some Korean text file encoded in 'euc-kr' in python but had some errors raised. After inspecting `encodings` module for a while, I learned that this module encodes Korean characters seemingly very weird way. Let me take an example

Korean character **탇** (which is an rarely used character, but i need this for pronunciation dictionary) is supposed to be encoded to **B5 6E** according to EUC-KR spec (I referred to [this site](https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/euc-kr.html)). But encodings module gives me somewhat different result.

```
# python3
>> from encodings import euc_kr
>> euc_kr.codec.decode(b'\xB5\x6E')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'euc_kr' codec cant decode byte 0xb5 in position 0: illegal multibyte sequence
>> euc_kr.codec.encode('탙')
(b'\xa4\xd4\xa4\xbc\xa4\xbf\xa4\xbc', 1)
```

As you can see, I get an error when I try to decode **B5 6E** and `euc_kr.codec.encode` gives me longer bytes than I expected. I have no clue what's happening there. How can I avoid raising an error when I decode **B5 6E**(and many other Korean characters)? Is there another document about EUC-KR specification that I can read to understand how python implementation of EUC-KR work?

Comment: Yes, that is odd. I'm not familiar with the euc encodings, but I don't understand why `euc_kr.codec.encode('탙')` results in so many bytes when euc_kr is supposed to encode each codepoint in 1 or 2 bytes. BTW, you don't need to use `euc_kr.codec.encode(s)`, you can just do `s.encode('euc_kr')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the `euc_kr` result is some kind of decomposition.  You might try `cp949`, which according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Unix_Code):

> The default Korean codepage for Windows (code page 949) is a proprietary, but upward compatible extension of EUC-KR...

Some experimentation:

```
>>> s = '탇'
>>> ud.name(s)
'HANGUL SYLLABLE TAD'
>>> s.encode('euc_kr')
b'\xa4\xd4\xa4\xbc\xa4\xbf\xa4\xa7'
>>> s.encode('euc_kr').decode('cp949')
'ㅤㅌㅏㄷ'
>>> for c in s.encode('euc_kr').decode('cp949'):
...     print(ud.name(c))
...     
HANGUL FILLER
HANGUL LETTER THIEUTH
HANGUL LETTER A
HANGUL LETTER TIKEUT
>>> s.encode('cp949').hex()
'b56e'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Everything is clear to me now. For your information, each Korean character consists of chosung, joongsung (, and jongsung optionally) but the grammar doesn't allow all possible combinations of the three. For example among '탓' and '탇', Korean grammar only allows '탓' as a valid Korean character.
But there are some cases where irregular Korean characters are allowed, like in pronunciation symbols. Actually, in the pronunciation symbol system, '탓' is not valid, but '탇' is.